# Should Client Secret for oAuth be rotated?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

For oAuth, we need a Client Id and Client Secret to generate the authentication tokens. Now I have couple of questions on this:

- Can the two values only be used for the application against which
  those are generated, meaning are those mapped to a single application only? If I share those credentials, can any other
  application use those?
- What is the general recommendation or practice, do we need to rotate
  the Client Secret (and/or Client Id)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here are the answers of your question:**

1. Yes, These credentials can only be used the against the application it is generated. In fact, `Client_id` is the key to identify that application. You can always use these credentials for multiple apps. You can compare `client_id` & `client_secret` with username & password. There can be only user entity behind a username & password. Similarly only one application is mapped to `client_id` & `client_secret`.
2. You don't need to rotate. but `client_secret` has expiry date which differs in various identity providers. *So the best practices are to store it securely & regenerate/update before it expires.*

**Take a look on this article for more insights:**
https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/

Comment: But what if client id is compromised as well? with client id and client secret combination, can anyone else create a mirror or duplicate application?

Comment: client id is generated automatically/randomly always and you can not change it. It can never match with other client id. Hence the combination is always unique.

Comment: but if client id and client secret both are compromised, does it mean that anyone with the combination can create a duplicate application? What can be done to prevent that other than storing it securely?

Comment: Bro, It's completely impossible to create duplicate application. Identity providers never asks you that what values do you want to set as client id and client secret. It is always randomly generated. Let's say if someone guessed(completely impossible) or stole client id & secret. They can generate access token using them. What identity providers are you using ?

Comment: Actually, I am from Security Team in my organization. I wish to know if I get hold of client id and secret, can I misuse them? How would the solution know if an authorized application is using the id and secret that the user has generated? Or if anyone has mirrored the application for his own ulterior motive.

Comment: I already responded all your questions. You can have a look at this article for deep dive : https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/